# Does the declaration or definition determine the scope of a variable in C++?

Tags: c++

Which determines the scope of a variable, the declaration or definition?

---

The documentation that I read says that the declaration determines the scope, but my own test said the contrary:

I get "undefined reference to i" error with the linker:

```
#include <iostream> // Stream declarations
using namespace std;
    extern int i; //declaration
int prueba();

int main() {
    int i; //Definition
    i=6;
    prueba();
} ///:~

int prueba(){
     cout << i; //cannot access to the scope of i;
}
```

Comment: This question only makes sense where the declaration is different from the definition, which is very rare. So, if you could give us an example of the case you're concerned with, I'm sure we could answer it.

Comment: Distinguishing between definition and declaration only makes sense for types/functions, doesn't it? Is it possible to make this distinction with variables?

Comment: I think like @Michael Burr also indicates that this question has an "easy" answer that just says the scope of a *name* is its declaration, and a "detailed but cumbersome" answer, that actually explains the scope of a variable and which has many special cases. Not sure what the question actually asks for.

Comment: @Jalf: Extern also distinguishes between decl and defn... but yeah, other than that...

Comment: The use of "declaration" and "definition" is confusing.  IMHO, a declaration is the first addition of a name to a scope, a redeclaration refers to a name that is already in the scope.  A definition can occur either in a declaration or in a redeclaration.  A definition is just a property of a declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Declaration. You can declare something external, and it's visible in that file, no matter where it was defined. Similarly, a function is visible anywhere it's declared.

Other than externs and functions though, I can't think of a way to declare a variable that doesn't also define it...

EDIT: OTOH, static (global) variables, the scope is determined by the definition, which is ALSO the declaration.

EDIT 2: Basically I think my point is that you can't really have a definition that isn't ALSO a declaration. so, the only interesting cases are where the declaration isn't also a definition, and that's basically extern with a global in another file, and function declarations...

Comment: In C++, using declarations are another way to declare something that doesn't define it.

Comment: @litb - I was sure there would be something C++ that I was forgetting about.  Even though they're not obscure, using declarations aren't exactly everyday things (at least for me).

Comment: using doesn't really separate the decl and defn, it more changes where the scope is... like making the {   } not continious or something...  but yeah, it does do wacky things to scope.

Comment: This is what i like in C, actually :) Things are clearly defined and you can answer such a question by quoting one paragraph of the standard. In C++, these things are weird and even the Standard's notion of scope is in error ( http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#554 ). One time it's a name that has scope, another time it's the object/variable that has a scope and temporaries suddenly are "local objects" without having defined this term anywhere.

Comment: Another non-definition declaration would be a class (forward) declaration.

Comment: @MSalters yeah, I would say that that's equivalent (But different) to function prototypes...

Comment: Yeah and those aren't variables. Actually, only named objects are variables. Functions and types aren't.

Comment: @litb: Yes, I was expanding the answer a bit. In the context of the original question, only extern is really relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Both determine the scope - it's just that they determine the scope of subtly different things.

The definition of an object in C/C++ determines at which scope the actual object is visible in and determines the 'largest scope' of visibility for an object or function.

The declaration determines at which scope a particular 'instance' of the name is visible in.

For example, a global variable is defined at global scope (of course) and is potentially visible at global scope or a tighter scope. But the following declaration of the global variable, `g_var`, is only visible within function `foo()`:

```
void foo(void)
{
    extern int g_var;    // the variable g_var has global scope, but this
                         //    declaration has function-level scope

    printf( "g_var is: %d\n", g_var);
}
```

[Brian Postow's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645743/does-the-declaration-or-definition-determine-the-scope-of-a-variable-in-c-c/1645786#1645786) that this distinction really only applies to global variables and functions is a a good one to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It enters scope at the ... declarator of the definition. so

```
int x=3;
{
  int x=x; // x is initialized to itself, uninitialized.
}
```

The iso c++ spec is unfortunately not freely available, so I can't quote chapter and verse.

Answer (score 0):

The definition determines the scope.

Answer (score 0):

From the [online version](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) of the C standard:

> 6.1.2.3 A label name is the only kind of identifier that has function scope.
>   It can be used (in a goto statement)
>   anywhere in the function in which it
>   appears, and is declared implicitly by
>   its syntactic appearance (followed by
>   a : and a statement).
>
> 6.2.1.4  Every other identifier has scope determined by the placement of
>   its **declaration** (in a declarator or
>   type specifier). If the declarator or
>   type specifier that declares the
>   identifier appears outside of any
>   block or list of parameters, the
>   identifier has file scope, which
>   terminates at the end of the
>   translation unit. If the declarator or
>   type specifier that declares the
>   identifier appears inside a block or
>   within the list of parameter
>   declarations in a function definition,
>   the identifier has block scope, which
>   terminates at the end of the
>   associated block. If the declarator or
>   type specifier that declares the
>   identifier appears within the list of
>   parameter declarations in a function
>   prototype (not part of a function
>   definition), the identifier has
>   function prototype scope, which
>   terminates at the end of the function
>   declarator. If an identifier
>   designates two different entities in
>   the same name space, the scopes might
>   overlap. If so, the scope of one
>   entity (the inner scope) will be a
>   strict subset of the scope of the
>   other entity (the outer scope). Within
>   the inner scope, the identifier
>   designates the entity declared in the
>   inner scope; the entity declared in
>   the outer scope is hidden (and not
>   visible) within the inner scope.

Emphasis mine.